# object copy happens even with move constructor defined when RVO disabled

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I happened to find a scenario where I am returning an object from a function by value.

With a conditional statement at the return statement, [RVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) is avoided.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class myObject {
    public:
    myObject() {
        std::cout <<"Default Constructor called" << std::endl;
        buffer = new char[1000];
        this->sz = 1000;
    }
    myObject(std::size_t sz) {
        buffer = new char[sz];
        this->sz = sz;
    }
    myObject(const myObject& other) {
        std::cout <<"Copy Constructor called" << std::endl;
        buffer = new char[other.sz];
        sz = other.sz;
        std::memcpy(buffer,other.buffer,other.sz);
    }

    myObject(myObject&& other) noexcept {
        std::cout <<"Move Constructor called" << std::endl;
        buffer = other.buffer;
        sz = other.sz;
        other.buffer = NULL;
        other.sz = 0;
    }
    myObject& operator=(myObject&& other) noexcept {
        std::cout <<"Move Assignment called" << std::endl;
        if(buffer != NULL) {
            delete[] buffer;
            sz = 0;
        }
        buffer = other.buffer;
        sz = other.sz;
        other.buffer = NULL;
        other.sz = 0;
        
        return *this;
    }
    
    myObject& operator=(const myObject& other) {
        // self ref ignored
        std::cout <<"Copy Assignment called" << std::endl;
        if(buffer != NULL) {
            delete[] buffer;
            sz = 0;
        }
        buffer = new char[other.sz];
        sz = other.sz;
        std::memcpy(buffer,other.buffer,other.sz);
        return *this;
    }
    ~myObject() {
        std::cout <<"~myObject()" << std::endl;
        if(buffer != NULL) {
            delete[] buffer;
            buffer = NULL;
        }
    }
    char * buffer = NULL;
    std::size_t sz = 0;
};


myObject GetObject_Complex(int x,int y) {
    myObject obj;
    myObject d;
    return x > y ? obj : d; // intentionaly made conditional to avoid Return value optimization
}

int main() {

    myObject c = GetObject_Complex(1,0); // Why move constructor is not called here ?

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    myObject d = std::move(c);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    myObject e;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    e = std::move(d);

}
```

Here the output using `g++ -g -std=c++11` `gcc version 7.5.0`

```
Default Constructor called
Default Constructor called
Copy Constructor called
~myObject()
~myObject()


Move Constructor called


Default Constructor called


Move Assignment called
~myObject()
~myObject()
~myObject()
```

It seems that in the line `myObject c = GetObject_Complex(1,0)`, copy operation is happening. But as per my understanding, when RVO is disabled and the object is defined with move operation, move constructor should be called.

Why move construction is not happening here? Am I missing something?

Thank You.

Comment: The same trick that avoids RVO, also avoids the special case that says it's OK to move from a named non-temporary local variable in `return` statement.

Comment: okay, I was looking for a test to disable RVO and move should be working, so I added the nontrivial return statement.

Comment: `return std::move(x > y ? obj : d);` would work the way you expect, I think.

Comment: Yes it works. Thank You. And I just got to know that with the `gcc` flag `-fno-elide-constructors` also RVO can be disabled without having a complicated return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that in the line `myObject c = GetObject_Complex(1,0)`, copy operation is happening.

Sort of but not quite. More accurately, the copy operation happens within `GetObject_Complex` when the
result of the ternary conditional operator is copied to the temporary return value.

> Why move construction is not happening here?

There is no move constructor because the compiler elided the move from the result of the function call as an optimisation.